# Spring ContextConfiguration initializer running too late in Spring Boot 2.1.0

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-test

I had a SpringBootTest that had this configuration on a `@SpringBootTest`:

```
@ContextConfiguration(initializers = RandomPortPropertySourceContextInitializer.class)
```

where the `RandomPortPropertySourceContextInitializer` looks like the following:

```
public class RandomPortPropertySourceContextInitializer implements
    ApplicationContextInitializer<ConfigurableApplicationContext> {

  @Override
  public void initialize(ConfigurableApplicationContext applicationContext) {
    RandomPortPropertySource randomPortPropertySource = new RandomPortPropertySource("randomPort");
    applicationContext.getEnvironment().getPropertySources().addAfter(
        StandardEnvironment.SYSTEM_ENVIRONMENT_PROPERTY_SOURCE_NAME, randomPortPropertySource);
  }
}
```

I could then use properties assigned from it in my test profile, such as:

```
oauth2.authorizationUri: http://localhost:${randomPort.wireMock}/mock/authorize
```

This convention was taken from various Spring-related posts, and is used to assign random available ports to helper processes on startup of the test. This all worked fine in Spring Boot 1.5.x, 2.0, etc. but once upgrading to Spring Boot 2.1.0 this initializer seems to run later, and now I get errors on startup such as:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "${randomPort.app}"
```

Something with the ordering on how the initializers run has changed, which causes this use case to fail. If I remove the config file usages to allow the startup to not blow up, the initializer does get run, but it's too late at that point.

I tried looking for information on this change in release notes but didn't notice anything. Any ideas/suggestions?

Comment: I suggest registering an issue in the Spring Boot Github as this [sh|c]ould be considered a regression imho.